# Blur the edges of a backdrop-filter element with CSS

Tags: html, css, webkit, css-filters, gaussianblur

```js
document.querySelector( 'style' ).innerHTML += `
  div {
    width: 40rem;
    height: 1rem;
    background-color: #444;
  }
  .earth_orbit, .moon {
    width: 15rem;
    margin-left: 100%;
    background-color: #222;;
  }
  .earth_orbit::before {
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
    background-color: #08f;
  }
  .moon {
    width: 2.5rem;
    height: 2.5rem;
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
  section {
    right: 5%;
    width: 37.5%;
    height: 50%;
    font-size: 5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    backdrop-filter: blur( 2rem );
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur( 2rem );
    /* filter: blur( 1rem ); */ /* Only blur inside element, ignoring the paremter */
  }
`;
```

```css
*, * ::before, * ::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body, main {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #111;
  color: #eee;
}
html {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1.5vmin;
}
main, div, section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
div, div::before, section {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: auto;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: #f90;
  border-radius: 5rem;
  content: '';
}
.moon::before {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<style>
  .sun_orbit, .earth_orbit, section {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  span {
    color: #ccc;
    font-size: 4rem;
  }
  .rotate {
    animation-name: rotate;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  }
  @keyframes rotate {
    0% { transform: rotate( 0deg ); }
    100% { transform: rotate( 360deg ); }
  }
  .offset {
    animation-duration: 1s;
  }
</style>
<main>
  <div class='sun_orbit rotate'>
    <div class='earth_orbit rotate offset'>
      <div class='moon'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <section>
    <p>blurred overlay<br><span>( backdrop-filter )</span></p>
  </section>
</main>
```

Where the CSS property `backdrop-filter` is used there are always sharp edges along the elements border. However to blur the edges themselves along with all content underneath is the desired result. setting `filter: blur( *value* )` on the target element doesn't seem to do the trick in any browser i've tested.

[image]

There's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57700730/how-to-fade-edges-of-backdrop-filter-blur) question asked over a year ago with no answer and perhaps not as clear an example of what is trying to be accomplished here. Every time the 'planets' go behind the blurred div you can see a clear edge of where the div begins and ends - like crisp glass. I'd like to find a way to maintain all the effects here but blur that edge or border along the 'glass' or backdropped overlay.

Answer (score 1):

The only work-around I found was faking `backdrop-filter` blur by duplicating all elements to be affected then creating a "window" overlapping the background positioned to it's exact location with a regular `filter: blur( n )` applied.

```js
document.querySelector( 'style' ).innerHTML += `
  .earth_orbit, .moon {
    width: 15rem;
    margin-left: 100%;
    background-color: #222;;
  }
  .earth_orbit::before {
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
    background-color: #08f;
  }
  .moon::before {
    display: none;
  }
  .moon {
    width: 2.5rem;
    height: 2.5rem;
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
  .sun_orbit, .earth_orbit {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  footer {
    right: 5%;
    width: 20rem;
    height: 20rem;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  .rotate {
    animation-name: rotate; animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-timing-function: linear; animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  }    
`;
```

```css
*, * ::before, * ::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body, main {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #111;
  color: #eee;
}
html {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1.5vmin;
}
main, div, footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
div, div::before, footer {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: auto;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: #f90;
  border-radius: 5rem;
  content: '';
}
div {
  width: 40rem; height: 1rem;
  background-color: #444;
}
```

```html
<style>
  footer .sun_orbit { top: 9.5rem; left: -13.25vmax; }
  section { width: 70%; height: 70%; }
  p { 
    position: relative; z-index: 10; font-size: 2rem; left: 30vh;
  }
  footer {
    overflow: hidden; background-color: #111;
    z-index: 10; filter: blur( 1rem ); left: 54.5vmax;
  }  
  @keyframes rotate {
    0% { transform: rotate( 0deg ); } 
    100% { transform: rotate( 360deg ); }
  } 
  .offset { animation-duration: 1s; }  
</style>
<main>
  <div class='sun_orbit rotate'>
    <div class='earth_orbit rotate offset'>
      <div class='moon'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <section>
      <div class='sun_orbit rotate'>
        <div class='earth_orbit rotate offset'>
          <div class='moon'></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </footer>
  <p>backdrop overlay<br>with faded edges</p>
</main>
```

Added benefit is this whole effect now works in Firefox when at first it didn't. Also: This could be made responsive if so desired.